# What is a Visual Studio project with the file extension *.ump

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution which contains a project with the file extension .ump . This project cannot be loaded.

What is this project type and how can it be loaded?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 professional. 
Bonus info: the solution build fine without this project and the application runs too.

Comment: I think this is a Visual Studio **UML Modelling Project**. I think you only can open/edit these Projects with VisualStudio Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altova UML modelling tools save files as .ump files.  I would suggest it is a representation of the application model saved alongside your source.